# how to get metadata from image using flutter image.network

Tags: image, flutter, dart, metadata, exif

i'm showing images in my flutter app using

`Image.network('link...')`

I want to show to the user how old is that image, using the exif, showing the modification/creation time of that file, or another way around

Answer (score -1):

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/jpg/your_image.jpg');
var list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

final data = await readExifFromBytes(list);
```

For more, read [exif](https://pub.dev/packages/exif)